# Red Underline selected text in richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, selectedtext

```
while ((indice = TextBox_stampa_contenuto.Text.IndexOf(parola, inizioParola)) != -1)
{
     TextBox_stampa_contenuto.Select(indice, parola.Length);
     TextBox_stampa_contenuto.SelectionFont = new Font(TextBox_stampa_contenuto.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Underline); 
     inizioParola = indice + parola.Length;
}
```

This part of code looks for a specified word and underlines it. How can I set it to underline like bad spelling in MS Word?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the .net version? if you are using .net 3.0+ and WPF then you can use Spell check class object.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at

[SpellCheckClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.spellcheck%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)